# PowerBuilder - Populate items in treeview using PFC

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-pfc

I have a window inherited from pfc_w_sheet and it contains treeview inherited from u_tv. Below is the script inside the window's open event. At first, it only have 1 argument  and the treeview successfully populated and displayed the items. But when the datawindow: d_app_usermenu1 has been modified, inner join and retrieval argument user_id has been added. And la_arg[2] has been added as well in windows open event, the treeview failed to populate the items in the run-time. 
Found out that the return value in tv_main.of_SetDatasource is -2 which means the DataWindow object did not have any key columns assigned, this is according to the remarks in pfc_u_tv. and I went to check below line of script that returned the -2 value. of_CreateKey function basically, add a computed column to the datawindow object that will contain all the keys concatenated together. This is necessary to be able to find a unique row, this is according from the remarks in pfc_u_tv.

```
// Add a computed column to the DataWindow object that will
// contain all the keys concatenated together.  This is necessary
// to be able to find a unique row.
If of_CreateKey(inv_ds[ai_Level].ds_obj) = -1 Then
    // No key columns were defined
    inv_ds[ai_Level].s_DataWindow = ""
    Destroy inv_ds[ai_Level].ds_obj
    Return -2
End if
```

Any idea on how to deal with this or some work-around? The objective is to retrieve the items or menu that was assigned in the specific user id that's why i need to have an inner join in the SQL query of datawindow.

```
//Window's Open Event
Any la_arg[]
tv_main.of_SetDatasource(1, "d_app_usermenu1", SQLCA, "menu_name", "", FALSE, 1, 1)
tv_main.of_SetDatasource(2, "d_app_usermenu2", SQLCA, "menu_name", ":parent.1.parent_name", FALSE, 2, 2)
is_userid = Upper(Trim(gnv_App.of_getUserID( )))
la_arg[1] = '0'
la_arg[2] = is_userid
tv_main.of_InitialRetrieve(la_arg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the datawindow in the dw painter.

Go to Rows > Update Properties and select at least one column in the "Unique Key Column(s)" list.  Save and re-test.

When you added the join condition, PB no longer knew which table was updateable, and could no longer determine which column(s) made up the primary key of that table.

Whenever you're editing a datawindow query, and you get the message "PB has changed the update specifications" - that's the first place you need to go check...

-Paul Horan-
SAP